# Zipping pdf files and downloading is giving corrupted file in java

Tags: java

I have tried this code for other files like .txt and excel files and they all are working fine. Same code if I use for pdf files, it will not show any error but when the file is downloaded, the zip folder will be corrupted. Is there any separate reading and writing process for pdf files?

```
                   //create byte buffer
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    ZipOutputStream zout = new 
                    ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                    Files[] files = new File(location).listFiles();
                    for(File pdfFile: files)
                            {
                                   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
                                   zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(pdfFile);
                                   int length;
                                   while((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0)
                                    {
                                       zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                    }
                            zout.closeEntry();
                            fin.close();
                            }
                 zout.close();
```

Comment: PDF has nothing to do with this. They aren't special.

Comment: You've probably messed up. The code as pasted wouldn't compile (I notice a missing closing paren on the `.putNextEntry` line). Question not answerable if the code that causes the problem isn't actually in your question.

Comment: Instead of writing your own loop for copying a file, use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)).  I don’t know for certain whether that’s the cause of your problem, but using Files.copy can at least reduce the possible culprits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now. In the previous loop where I was creating the pdf files, the output stream was not closed and hence it was causing issue.